# Problem with Python plugin

Tags: qgis, python

I developed a Python plugin to import a PostgreSQL project organized in QGIS with one click. The problem is that I don't put the layers it in the correct "tree scheme" in the layer panel.

I enclose a photo of the piece of instruction.

[image: the code]

Comment: See [how to add layers to existing groups using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/add-layer-to-a-qgis-group-using-python/126587#126587).