# PyQGIS: New vector created inside group instead of TOC

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

```
def newPolygonVector(self):
    vlt = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:32647", "", "memory")
    vlt.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("id", QVariant.Int)])
    vlt.updateFields()
    self.MakeFile()
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(vlt, self.mypath + f'/FieldBorderPolygon{self.index}.shp',
                                              project.transformContext(), options)
    self.vlb = self.iface.addVectorLayer(self.mypath + f'/FieldBorderPolygon{self.index}.shp', "", "ogr")
    Symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple(
        {'color_border': '#3232fa', 'width_border': '1', 'style': 'no'})
    self.vlb.renderer().setSymbol(Symbol)
    self.vlb.startEditing()
    self.vlb.triggerRepaint()

def newLineVector(self):
    vlt = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=EPSG:32647", "", "memory")
    vlt.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("id"
                                               , QVariant.Int)])
    vlt.updateFields()
    self.MakeFile()
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(vlt, self.mypath + f'/RajahLine{self.index}.shp',
                                              project.transformContext(), options)
    self.vlr = self.iface.addVectorLayer(self.mypath + f'/RajahLine{self.index}.shp', "", "ogr")
    self.vlr.renderer().symbol().setWidth(0.6)
    self.vlr.renderer().symbol().setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 0))



def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False

    self.newLineVector()
    self.newPolygonVector()

    
    #Grouping
    root = project.layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.insertGroup(0, f"Prelining {self.index}")
    group.addLayer(self.vlb)
    group.addLayer(self.vlr)
    root.removeLayer(self.vlb)
    root.removeLayer(self.vlr)
```

1. These are some of my code snippet for one of the processes in a plugin and the plugin is iterable.
2. Whenever it runs the first time, it gets the result that I want, as it creates a 2 new vector **outside of a group in TOC**
3. But when it comes to the second time I run the plugin, it will create the first 2 vector inside the 1st group and then will add it into 2nd group having duplicated layer in **Group1 and Group2**
4. Results are shown below

1.1) This is the first time running the plugin and everything lays greatly inside the group:
[image]

1.2) When I click on the iterable plugin again, it will create the vector inside the previous group instead of outside the group:
[image]

1.3) Making me having 2 duplicated layers:
[image]

Comment: For adding your layers to the root, instead of to a group in the Layers panel, you need to write just that in your code. `root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()` and then `root.insertLayer(0, my_layer)`. On the other hand, you can read [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/add-layer-to-a-qgis-group-using-python/126587#126587) to know about the recommended way of adding layers to groups.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Hmm, it seems  my other function such as QgsProject.Instance().mapLayer(my_layer.id()) can't be detected using this method. Seems like there's no layer.id() occurs

Comment: Does the 3rd image show what you want or is it the result that you don't want but the script returns?

Comment: I have read your question many times but could not understand what exactly you needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I have a solution like this:

[image]

These are the lines I have changed or added:

```
def run(self):

    # other lines

    #Grouping
    root = self.project.layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.insertGroup(0, f"Prelining {self.index}")
    group.addLayer(self.vlb)
    group.addLayer(self.vlr)

    # root.removeLayer(self.vlb) <- no need these two lines
    # root.removeLayer(self.vlr) <-

def newLineVector(self):

    # other lines
    # ...

    # instead of self.iface.addVectorLayer
    self.vlr = QgsVectorLayer(
        self.mypath + f'/RajahLine{self.index}.shp',
        f"RajahLine{self.index}",  ## layer name
        "ogr")

    # renderer part
    # ...

def newPolygonVector(self):

    # other lines
    # ...

    # instead of self.iface.addVectorLayer
    self.vlb = QgsVectorLayer(
        self.mypath + f'/FieldBorderPolygon{self.index}.shp',
        f"FieldBorderPolygon{self.index}",  ## layer name
        "ogr")

    # symbol and renderer part
    # ...
```

QGIS ordinarily adds a new layer to the line before the active layer. In this case, it always adds to the top (pay attention to the 4th and 5th groups).

Comment: A minimal plugin using the structure above: [Link](https://we.tl/t-1fPs7Gqhb2)