# Viewing memory layers in group with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend, group-layer, memory-layer

I'm writing a plugin for QGIS and given a layer (`self.layer_comuni`) from this I extrapolate an indeterminate number of layers depending on the correspondence of the values of the `mercato_comuni` list with the `"COMUNI"` feature of the layer.

However, I cannot insert the layers obtained into a group, i.e. if I use `group_layer.addLayer(memory_layer)` I see them in the legend but not in the canvas, instead if I add them with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memory_layer)` I see them in the canvas but in the legend outside the group.

How can I get this to work?

```py
def checkAndBuilderGiurisdizione(self, lista_comuni :list):
    # crea il gruppo layer GIURISDIONE
    group_name = "GIURISDIZIONE"
    # cerca nella root se è già presente il gruppo
    self.lg.info(f"Ricerca del gruppo {group_name} nella root di QGis....")
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group_layer = root.findGroup(group_name)
    # se non lo è lo aggiunge e diventa attivo
    if not group_layer:
        self.lg.info("Gruppo non trovato e aggiunto....")
        group_layer = root.addGroup(group_name)
    else:
        self.lg.info("Gruppo già nel Project QGis.")


    selezioni :list = []
    for comune in lista_comuni:

        print(f"COMUNE : {comune}")

        self.layer_comuni.selectByExpression(f"\"COMUNE\"='{comune}'", QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

        selezioni.append(self.layer_comuni.selectedFeatures())

        memory_layer = self.layer_comuni.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(self.layer_comuni.selectedFeatureIds()))
        memory_layer.setName(f"{comune}")
        #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memory_layer, False)
        group_layer.addLayer(memory_layer)

    for selezione in selezioni:
        for feature in selezione:
            print(f"FEATURE COMUNE: {feature['COMUNE']}")
            print(f"FEATURE AREA: {feature['Shape_Area']}")

    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: Maybe I solved it like this, tell me if it's correct:

....
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memory_layer, False)
group_layer.addLayer(memory_layer)
....

Comment: Wolverine, yes- that is the correct approach. Add layer to project with  2nd argument set to `False` then add to group in the layer tree.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things regarding your code:

- work with [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and `children()` of the `QgsLayerTree` node, instead of only `if not group_layer:`:

  ```py
  for child in root.children():
      if not isinstance(group_layer, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
          self.lg.info("Gruppo non trovato e aggiunto....")
          group_layer = root.addGroup(group_name)
      else:
          self.lg.info("Gruppo già nel Project QGis.")
  ```
- to be sure one can also check the count of selected features with [`selectedFeatureCount()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a482a410d199e91a17be28cc32eb51092):

  ```py
  if self.layer_comuni.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
  ```
- `selezioni = []` or `selezioni = list()` are maybe a bit shorter than `selezioni :list = []`

Apart from the above suggestions, you are doing a brilliant job with adding a layer to a group, exactly how @GermánCarrillo suggested in this thread: [Adding layer to group using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/adding-layer-to-group-using-pyqgis).

```py
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memory_layer, False) 
group_layer.addLayer(memory_layer)
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 21. Cheat sheet for PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html)